# Extracting characters from an NSMutableString

Tags: objective-c

How does one extract characters from a NSMutableString?

Is it the same as NSString?

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c.png", [someString characterAtIndex:0]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that should work fine.  You can call any NSString method on a NSMutableString.